# How edit headformat with thmbox=M in \declaretheoremstyle

Tags: environments, thmtools, thmbox

good Saturday! I am making environments for demonstrations. I want to edit the "headformat" of an environment made with thmtools that has "thmbox = M", I want the number not to appear
when I use thmbox it doesn't recognize headformat, I tried putting headformat before thmbox but it doesn't recognize order of the declarations either.
So many thanks.

this is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt,  spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries\bfseries\itshape, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=.5em, %
name=Demostración,
numberwithin=,
thmbox=M,
headformat=\NAME~\NOTE %
%qed=$\blacksquare$
]{Demostracion}

\declaretheorem[style=Demostracion]{prueba}

\begin{document}
\begin{prueba}
\lipsum[2]
\end{prueba}
\end{document}
```

i want to delete what is in yellow
[image]

Comment: Why not use the key `numbered=no` rather than `numberwithin=`?

Comment: doesn't work in \declaretheoremstyle neither \declaretheorem, but i found sharenumber=no that's work. I think it would be good to close the question. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, thmtools' use of thmbox does not interact well (or in most cases, at all) with other style keys. You can change the style of thmbox theorems by passing more options to the `thmbox` key. You can find these options in the [thmbox documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmbox). Unfortunately, the way thmtools' implements the key requires **16** hashes for keys with parameters. There is a relevant [issue](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/issues/25) on the thmtools github page. Here's your desired output:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  name=Demostración,
  thmbox={M,headstyle={\bfseries ################1}},
  ]{Demostracion}

\declaretheorem[style=Demostracion]{prueba}

\begin{document}

\begin{prueba}
\lipsum[2]
\end{prueba}

\end{document}
```

In the `headstyle` key, we're just saying to ignore the number, which is contained in parameter `#2`.